# Magento as comparison website

Tags: multi-vendor, comparison

I'm looking for a platform to launch a comparison website. For example the website will sell specific product, lets call it product "x". Product "x" is provided by multiple suppliers. I want to list the product on the website and the suppliers.

Users are then able to click on a supplier link and arrive at the supplier website.

Is this possible with Magento, or should I look at another solution?

Thanks

Comment: This is for the OP directly as we are a little bored with tech only - stack exchange is not the best place to post business or combined business/technical questions. To generate $250,000/yr affiliate income at 7% you need to refer $3.5million via the site, $3.5million at $127 per order (Amazon average) means 28,000 orders/yr or 2,350/mth, with 1% conversion rate (high) equals 250,000 visitors per month - top end hosting is required such as clusters.

Comment: ShopStyle has 1.5million products, 20% of this or 300,000 products means processing half to one million+ products/day from 50+ retailer feeds automatically (many are excluded) and adding/removing/updating 1-10% of the 300,000 with data mapping and cleansing. If you only want low $10s thousands income (which 95-99% which have experience of) it is completely different than high $10s to $100s thousands income, the business dynamics and technical architecture fundamentally change, we solely look at top 5%/1% sites. Others will be able to help for the remaining 95%.

Answer (score 2):

Magento can handle this, but [requires a marketplace plugin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_marketplace) to achieve the type of functionality you're looking for, which handles the comparison of a product between two different suppliers.

This is usually achieved with a marketplace/dropshipping product bundle. One such plugin provider is [Unirgy](http://unirgy.com). This question has been answered a few times on Magento.SE, and I am hesitant to make a formal recommendation due to the fact that it is a commercial plugin and it is rather expensive.

That being said, I have used Unirgy Dropship and Marketplace on many implementations and have had success with it.

There are no free, open source alternatives at this time that accomplish all of the features that you will likely need.

Answer (score 0):

No it does not need a marketplace plugin, yes it can be done, but you would not want to do it. Magento is an eCommerce solution and built around this function, when you start to get to 10s thousands of products you have major issues, once you get to 100s thousands of products you have enterprise class problems, then you need to filter out the eCommerce functionality.

We know all this very simply, we work with and have used a Managed Affiliate Platform from multi-national consultants which works directly with Magento CE or EE. It has special tools to map, clean and upload up to millions of products as well as adjust Magento to an affiliate solution. On top of that you need very specialist hosting at very reduced prices due to the low margins on affiliate sites, they designed their own architecture to support it.

A new multi-million affiliate product site can be live in weeks with fully automated processing directly competing with affiliate sites like ShopStyle. ShopStyle generate around $1-1.5million revenue per site and sales of circa $20million for the retailers (around 7% commission). The architecture above we have worked with targets 20% of ShopStyle revenues, a site would cost $40-50,000 to implement. We ran 100,000 product affiliate sites with WordPress but it looks cheap regardless of what you do with it, and Google really does not like it compared to the same site based on Magento - they are squeezing non-enterprise (ShopStyle) sites very heavily.

If you want to build all this yourself with 100s thousands products it will be a multi-year road ahead regardless of the platform. You will need web clusters, and the most important supplier onboarding with automated data cleansing and mapping without having to change code to introduce a new supplier. Everything else is being slowly but surely delisted by Google and losing trust with consumers.

Comment: I appreciate the contrarian point of view and value your feedback. Personally this smells like FUD to me - I've built (many) Magento affiliate sites with 100's of thousands of products in < 3 months with marketplace functionality. This seems less like fact and more like your own personal experience and a plug for ShopStyle.

Comment: I'll have to take your word on it considering that Magento has a ~30% market share of the top 1M eCommerce sites; I cannot find any data at all on the number of registered affiliates or install base for PopSugar's Shopstyle affiliate program. Cheers.

Comment: Its total nonsense @philwinkle - this guy just makes up his answers, they never make sense and are almost always completely fictional. I've no idea at all why he is on here, as he simultaneously tries to sell his hosting/consultancy services at the same time as saying Magento is good for nothing. Just downvote him , its the only way to discourage him